# Batch Update Relationships

Tags: relationships

Is there a way to batch update relationships, specifically the type of relationship along with the start and end date?

I don't see the fields to add to a profile to do a batch update. I also don't see a way on import to add a start and end date to the relationship mapping.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible in one of two ways:

- Use the [API CSV Import GUI extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui).  This will allow you to import relationships with start/end dates.  As a matter of workflow, you'll probably end up exporting existing relationships and reimporting via the extension.
- Make the changes directly in SQL, in the `civicrm_relationship` table.

There's actions to add relationships between contacts and a household/organization in the search action menu, but what you're describing doesn't exist out of the box.  I certainly think it's a good candidate for a [sponsored improvement](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) though.

Comment: I'm trying to update the current relationships in CiviCRM through the import process.
There is no field for set active/inactive the current relationship in basic import process of CiviCRM.
Then I saw your solution, installed the extension and tried to inactive the current relationships.
I use contact_id_a and contact_id_b and relationship_type id and set the is_active to 0 in csv file. But this extension gives me an error "Error with entity "create"! (Duplicate Relationship)". I'm going to update this relationship but this extension tries to create a relationship and fails because this relatio

Answer (score 1):

With SearchKit, probably from version 5.43, it will be possible to do in-place edits of relationship fields as start and end dates, is active and custom fields. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21533